# updateOne deleting my data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Alright, so I've been tinkering with this all night and I have to sleep so I'm asking here. Why is `updateOne` deleting my data when it should just be updating it?

```
DB.collection('users').updateOne({"name":"bob"}, {"age":"20"}, (e,i) => {

    console.log(i);

});
```

`i.result.ok` prints `1`, but when I go to search for `bob` after doing this, the data is gone entirely, vanished.

My first question is why is this happening, my second is how can I update, since apparently this isn't the way to do it.

I can run find({"name":"bob"}) just fine before hand, so the data does exist before running this.

After, it is gone. Help please, my blood pressure is getting way too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:-

You need to use `$set` to update specific fields. `{}` give blank, if there is no find query.

```
DB.collection('users').updateOne({"name":"bob"},{$set: {"age":"20"} });
```

To get your answers, refer [mongodb-update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#example-update-specific-fields).

Hope this will hep you solving the problem.

Comment: Yep, that did it! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you :)